# Ctrl+L to copy modifier from an object to another does not work

Tags: modifiers

What is it that I do wrong? When I click ctrl + L instead of the copy menu, a Make Links menu opens instead (Object to Scene, Object Data, Materials etc are in that menu). Please help...

Comment: Copy Modifier should be at the bottom of this pop-up, or you can enable the Copy Attributes addon and use Ctrl C but it doesn't answer your question...

Comment: Ctrl+L is the _Link/Transfer Data_ tool, so it is absolutely correct that this menu appears. _Copy Modifiers_ should be in the list, too. If it is not working it might be that you are not using it correct. It copies modifiers from the active selected object to the other selected objects - which means, you have to select the objects that should receive the modifiers and the one that has the modifiers to be copied.